# iron:router redirect not admin user

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to prevent some users to enter specific routes. I'va seen examples for not logged users:

```
Router.onBeforeAction
(
    function () 
    {
        if (!Meteor.userId())
            this.redirect('/');
        else
            this.next();
    }
);
```

But when I try

```
Router.onBeforeAction
(
    function () 
    {
        if ( !isadmin( Meteor.userId() ) && Router.current().route.getName()=='admin' )
            this.redirect('/');
        else
            this.next();
    }
);
```

I receive the next message

> iron_core.js?hash Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to
>   call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this and worked

```
Template.admin.onRendered(function() {
   if ( !isadmin( Meteor.userId() ) )
   {
        Router.go('/');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Router.route('/your-url',{
    name:'routeName',
    onBeforeAction:function(){
        if(checkSomething){
            //check passed, continue routing
            this.next();
        } else {
            //check failed, redirect.
            Router.go('/not-authorized');
        }
    },

    action: function(){
         this.render('templateName');
    }
});
```